# read value true for a specific cell only

Tags: php, phpexcel

i am reading a excel file with the help of phpexcel , issue is when ever i try to read a specific colum which contain % sign i dnt read the correct value , i have set

```
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
```

which i think sets it true for the whole file , if i remove this line i do get the right values from that specific colum but my rest of code gets useless for the rest of my file , is there a away i set this true for that colum only . or any other solution ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're using `->getCellValue()` ?

Try : `->getCalculatedValue()`